# How to understand the gensim's iter parameter and its implication on preprocessing?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

```
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
from gensim import utils

class MyCorpus(object):
    """An interator that yields sentences (lists of str)."""

    def __iter__(self):
        corpus_path = datapath('lee_background.cor')
        i = 1
        print(str(i))
        for line in open(corpus_path):
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace

            yield utils.simple_preprocess(line)

import gensim.models

sentences = MyCorpus()
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, iter=1)
```

This is the genism's documentation code from https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html.

I have 2 questions regarding the iter parameter:

1) when it is set to 1, why is the print(str(i)) executed twice?

2) when the "iter=10", the 'simple_preprocess' is executed 11 times. If my own customized 'preprocess' is very heavy, is this going to be very slow? How to avoid this preprocessing repetitions in using genism word2vec?

Answer (score 1):

The gensim `Word2Vec` class needs to iterate through your corpus once to discover the full vocabulary, then `iter` times for training. So you'll see your corpus iterable used `iter + 1` times.

Yes, if your preprocessing is expensive, it's wasteful to repeat it for every iteration. You can do it once, writing the results to a separate interim file where each token is separate by a space (`' '`). Then, you've only spent the preprocessing effort once, and when you later train `Word2Vec`, you perform only the (very simple and cheap) splitting-by-space tokenization.

Comment: That seems a little more cumbersome. Is this good practice to use genism this way?

Comment: What seems cumbersome?

Comment: I meant first to have a utility to do the tokenization once and output the results into a separate file. Then use genism to use the tokenized data to training. It would be nice this can be in one workflow all within genism.

Comment: Well, gensim needs to go through the data `iter + 1` times. If your iteraable object needs to go through an expensive preprocessing/tokenization each time, that will cost extra runtime. If you don't want that redundancy, you'll have to do that once & cache the result. Is it 'cumbersome' to perform a caching optimization? Not really; it's very common & beneficial, & there's no other way to get the benefit.

Comment: I am processing a 100G plain text and cache them may be too much memory?

Comment: The suggestion was to write the preprocessed /tokenized text to a **separate  interim file**. (If you had a high-memory machine, you could consider caching it in RAM, instead. Amazon now offers rental instances with up to 24,000GB of RAM.) But yes, if you don't have enough disk space or RAM to store the preprocessed/tokenized data, but only store your raw data, then you'd necessarily have to redundantly preprocess/tokenize the data all `iter + 1` times, in order to feed the right format to `Word2Vec`.